# having a dictionary of matrices, how to return a dictionary containing the matrix with the smallest number of zeros?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing matrices, I want for each matrix count the number of zero and return a dictionary containing the element with the minimum of zero
To do this I have already the method to count the number of zero, and how to have the matrix with the minimum of zero, but I did not know how to return the pair.

[image]

```
Dictionary<string, int[,]> c
        foreach ( int[,] entry in c.Values)
        {
            //array to contain the number of zeros
              int[] max_couverture = new int[c.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < max_couverture.Length; i++)
                {
             //calcul_zero the method that calculate the number of zero of a matrix
                    max_couverture[i] = calcul_zero(entry);
                }
                int min = max_couverture[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < max_couverture.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (max_couverture[i] < min) min = max_couverture[i];

                    i++;
                }


        }
//calculate the number of zero of a matrix
 public static  int calcul_zero(int[,] m)
    {
        int colIdx = 0; // column index to check
        int num = Enumerable.Range(0, m.GetLength(0)).Count(i => m[i, colIdx] == 0);
        return num;
    }
```

Comment: there will be the edge case of many matrices with only zeroes. there is no point in declaring the tracker variable for the maximum (`max_couverture`) inside the loop, you want a result over all iterated `entry`. update your post with a minimal, complete example that actually compiles, currently it is unclear where the problem arises because the code is incomplete. for example the definition of `calcul_zero`.

Comment: Do I understand correct, you want to return the min and max of each matrix?

Comment: Return List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using facilities which are already there by decomposing the problem. First, unfortunately, `int[,]` does not implement `IEnumerable<int>`, which can be addressd with the following extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T[,] target)
{
    foreach (var item in target)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Next, we can use Linq to define a function which counts the number of zeros in a two-dimensional array as follows.

```
public static int CountZeros(int[,] iMat)
{
    return iMat.ToEnumerable<int>().Count(iInt => 0 == iInt);
}
```

Surprisinlgy, Linq also does not provide an extension method to determine an element of a sequence which is maximal or minimal if a certain function is applied to it. This can be done with the following two extension methods.

```
public static T ArgMin<T, R>(T t1, T t2, Func<T, R> f)
where R : IComparable<R>
{
    return f(t1).CompareTo(f(t2)) > 0 ? t2 : t1;if equal
}

public static T ArgMin<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> Sequence, Func<T, R> f)
where R : IComparable<R>
{
    return Sequence.Aggregate((t1, t2) => ArgMin<T, R>(t1, t2, f));
}
```

Finally, we can define a method returning a dictionary which contains the first key and value matrix for which the number of zeros is minimal.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int[,]> MinNumOfZeros(Dictionary<string, int[,]> iDict)
{
    var KeyOfMinimum = iDict.Keys.ArgMin(iKey => CountZeros(iDict[iKey]));
    return new Dictionary<string, int[,]> { { KeyOfMinimum, iDict[KeyOfMinimum] } };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by modifying your calcul_zero a bit. ie:

```
{
// ...
var minKV = c.ToList()
    .OrderBy(k => calcul_zero(k.Value))
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(minKV.Key);
//...
}
public static int calcul_zero(int[,] m)
{
    int zeros=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (m[i, j] == 0) zeros++;
        }
    }
    return zeros;
}
```